# How to define a data variable in Vue using API's

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm doing a little project for showing movies from an API (TMDb) using Vue Routers. So I have a component called 'MovieList' where I connect to the API.

This is my data:

```
data() {
  return {
    movies: []
  }
}
```

These are my methods:

```
methods: {
  getMovies: () => new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=MyAPI`;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).results);
      } else {
        reject(Error(xhr.statusText));
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
  })
}
```

and my mounted:

```
mounted() {
  this.getMovies().then(
    result => get(result)
  )
  function get(result) {
    result.forEach((el) =>  {
      this.movies = el
    })
  }
}
```

So, what I want is that the obtained array equals the variable 'movies' declared in 'data'.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]


And this is the error I get in console:

```
MovieList.vue?ea6b:34 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'movies' of undefined
    at eval (MovieList.vue?ea6b:36)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at get (MovieList.vue?ea6b:35)
    at eval (MovieList.vue?ea6b:30)
```

Thanks everyone, hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

The code in your `mounted` hook is a bit strange.

If you want to assign the `result` to your `movies` array, all you really need is

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ movies: [] }),

  // use the "created" hook as it executes earlier
  // and there's no obvious reason to wait longer
  async created () {
    // directly assign the result array to "movies"
    this.movies = await this.getMovies()
  },


  methods: {
    // you don't need to change "getMovies" 
    // but we've come a long way since XMLHttpRequest
    async getMovies () {
      const res = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=MyAPI')
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw res
      }
      return (await res.json()).results
    }
  }
}
```

Your issue was that inside your `get` function, `this` does not refer to the Vue instance.

You also appeared to be trying to overwrite `movies` with each result in the array which would end up with you only storing the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what data type API returns， but you can try this

```
mounted() {
    let _this = this
    _this.getMovies().then(result => {
        _this.movies = result
    })
}
```

Comment: No need to use `_this` when using an arrow function

Comment: Right！I'm out of habit